# Disable cookies and clear cache in Chrome Custom Tabs

Tags: android, cookies, chrome-custom-tabs

I am using Chrome Custom Tabs to redirect users to a link of an 3rd party site. But, I want the cookies to be disabled and cache cleared in the resultant chrome custom tab (just like if the link would have opened in the incognito mode of google chrome). I have searched through the documentation , but could not find a way to achieve this. Kindly help

Answer (score 1):

Chrome Custom Tabs share cookies with regular Chrome by design. If you *don't* want cookies to be shared and/or want to have control over the cache, consider using a WebView, which runs in your own process and doesn't share any data with Chrome.

Comment: There are certain security reason we don't want to use WebView. Is there anyway to disable cookies in CCT?